# My Custom Reinforcement Learning Environment is unable to extract values that I want

Tags: python, list, environment, reinforcement-learning, empty-list

I am working on a grid optimization model where I am importing data from a data-set and I am training my RL-model on a custom Reinforcement Learning environment. In this model I also want to extract my grid values and pv-values step by step. While training, my custom Reinforcement learning environment does give me values for grid and pv but when I do prediction, it outputs an empty list. I wanted to ask why is it so.
What's the problem?

**For Importing the dataset**

```
def get_data(start = '2017-01-01 00:00:00', end = '2017-01-01 23:55:00'):

    # import standard load profiles

    slp = pd.read_csv('df_p.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)['0'] / 1000
    slp = slp.resample('15min').mean() * 3

    pv = pd.read_csv('Solar_Data-2011.csv', delimiter=';',
                    index_col=0, parse_dates=False)["Generation"] * 3
    pv.index = slp.index
    print("Load values:")
    print(slp.values)
    print("PV values:")
    print(pv.values)
    start = pd.to_datetime(start)
    end = pd.to_datetime(end)
    
    return slp[start:end], pv[start:end]
```

**This is my custom-environment**

```
class CostEnv(Env):
    def __init__(self):
        # Actions we can take increase in cost, lowering of cost
        self.action_space = Discrete(2)    
        ### Get input data, just choose one day for now
        self.load, self.pv = get_data(start = '2017-01-01 00:00:00', end = '2017-01-01 23:55:00')
        self.pv_price = 0.10
        self.grid_price = 0.40
        self.line_max = 15
        self.grid_penalty = 100
        self.battery_max = 18
        self.battery_state = 10
        self.pv_values = []
        self.grid_values = []
        ###
        
        # Set episode length
        self.episode_length = len(self.load)
        
        self.observation_space = Dict(
            {
                "load": Box(0, self.episode_length - 1, shape=(2,), dtype=int),
                "pv": Box(0, self.episode_length - 1, shape=(2,), dtype=int),
            }
        )
        
    def step(self, action):
        # Apply action
        # 0 -1 = -1 decrease in cost
        # 1 -1 = 0 Increase in cost
        # self.state += action -1 
        # Reduce episode length by 1 second
        # self.episode_length -= 1 ###Move to the end of the action
        ### We calculate the reward based on the price for the electricity,
        #lower price, "higher" reward
        if action == 0:
            # Take all electricity from grid
            if self.load[len(self.load)-self.episode_length] > self.line_max:
                reward = self.load[len(self.load)-self.episode_length] * self.grid_price * -1 - abs(self.load[len(self.load)-self.episode_length] - self.line_max) * self.grid_penalty
                self.grid_values.append(self.load[len(self.load)-self.episode_length])
            else:
                reward = self.load[len(self.load)-self.episode_length] * self.grid_price * -1
                self.grid_values.append(self.load[len(self.load)-self.episode_length])
            
        elif action == 1:
            # Take all electricity from pv
            if self.pv[len(self.pv)-self.episode_length] >= self.load[len(self.load)-self.episode_length]:
                if abs(self.pv[len(self.pv)-self.episode_length] - self.load[len(self.load)-self.episode_length]) > self.line_max:
                    reward = self.load[len(self.load)-self.episode_length] * self.pv_price * -1 - (self.pv[len(self.pv)-self.episode_length] - self.load[len(self.load)-self.episode_length]) * self.grid_penalty
                    self.pv_values.append(self.pv[len(self.pv)-self.episode_length])
                else:
                    reward = self.load[len(self.load)-self.episode_length] * self.pv_price * -1
                    self.pv_values.append(self.pv[len(self.pv)-self.episode_length])
            else:
                if (self.load[len(self.load)-self.episode_length] - self.pv[len(self.pv)-self.episode_length]) > self.line_max:
                    reward = self.pv[len(self.pv)-self.episode_length] * self.pv_price * -1 - (self.load[len(self.load)-self.episode_length] - self.pv[len(self.pv)-self.episode_length]) * self.grid_price - (self.load[len(self.load)-self.episode_length] - self.pv[len(self.pv)-self.episode_length]) * self.grid_penalty
                    self.pv_values.append(self.pv[len(self.pv)-self.episode_length])
                else:
                    reward = self.pv[len(self.pv)-self.episode_length] * self.pv_price * -1
                    self.pv_values.append(self.pv[len(self.pv)-self.episode_length])
            ### This may lead the agent to always choose action 1, 
            ###because it will always supply the demand and will always be cheaper.
        
        else:
            reward = -300000
            # Invalid action
            #raise ValueError(f'Invalid action: {action}')       
        info = {}
        
        ### Observation
        observation = {
            "load": (0,self.load[len(self.load)-self.episode_length]),
            "pv": (0,self.pv[len(self.pv)-self.episode_length]),
            }
        
        ### Either here or before checking self.episode_length
        self.episode_length -= 1
        ### Check if timeseries is over
        if self.episode_length <= 0: 
            done = True
        else:
            done = False
        
        # Return step information
        # return self.state, reward, done, info
        return observation, reward, done, info

    def render(self):
        # Implement viz
        pass
    
    def reset(self):
        self.done=False
        # Set episode length
        self.episode_length = len(self.load)
        
        observation = {
            "load": (0, self.load[len(self.load)-self.episode_length]),
            "pv": (0, self.pv[len(self.pv)-self.episode_length]),
            }
        
        return observation
```

**Here is my model-training**

```
log_path = os.path.join('Training', 'Logs')

model = A2C("MultiInputPolicy", env, verbose=1, tensorboard_log=log_path)

model.learn(total_timesteps=300000)
```

**The values extracted by this model are as follows:**

```
Env.grid_values: [0.4014,
 0.342,
 0.5357999999999999,
 0.4698,
 0.44999999999999996,
 0.376,
 0.521,
 0.4293999999999999,
 0.25140000000000007,
 0.7412000000000001,
```

```
env.pv_values:[0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0607460715,
 0.0678108435,
 0.07642341180000001,
```

**Now for predicting, I am using another dataset which is used as follows:**

```
def get_data(start = '2017-01-01 00:00:00', end = '2017-01-01 23:55:00'):

    # import standard load profiles

    slp = pd.read_csv('df_p.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)['2'] / 1000
    slp = slp.resample('15min').mean() * 3

    pv = pd.read_csv('Solar_Data-2011.csv', delimiter=';',
                    index_col=0, parse_dates=False)["Generation"] * 3
    pv.index = slp.index
    print("Load values:")
    print(slp.values)
    print("PV values:")
    print(pv.values)
    start = pd.to_datetime(start)
    end = pd.to_datetime(end)
    
    return slp[start:end], pv[start:end]
```

**For prediction the code is this**

```
episodes = 20

for ep in range(episodes):
    obs = env.reset()
    done = False
    while not done:
        action = model.predict(obs)
        obs, rewards, done, info = env.step(action)

env.close()
```

The lists are as following:

```
env.pv_values

[]

env.grid_values

[]
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong. Also, I load the model in a separate Jupyter notebook and environment is the same that I use for training my model. The code is as follows:

```
model = A2C("MultiInputPolicy",env=env)
model = model.load("A2C_Multi_Input_Policy_Improved_1",env=env)
```

Comment: Where is the output `env.pv_values` coming from? There is no such print statement.

Comment: In Jupyter notebook if you just type the statement and run the cell it delivers the output

Comment: At what point of this long code do you type it?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I had printed it in my cell even then it gave me an empty list.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Once I had trained my model then I use a separate cell to print it out to check whether the values are appended or not to the list. Similarly after predictions using my model, I used a separate cell to print it out and then it gives me the output which is an empty list.

Comment: And where in the code did you expect `env.pv_values` to be filled? Oh, I see, in `step`. So then it seems it is time for you to do some debugging to see if `step` is called at all, and what the value of `action` is and if the conditions are true inside which `self.pv_values.append` is called.

Comment: if you look at my custom environment which is of class CostEnv(Env), there you would see under respective actions, I have made the list to append the values. For example under action 0 there is self.grid_values appending the values and under action 1 there is self.pv_values appending the values. I am not quite sure I could copy and paste the code here.

Comment: One more strange thing that happened was that the agent rather than taking action 0 or acion 1 directly jumps onto the else statement which is a penalty of reward = -300000. And it does not take any subsequent action. During training the values do get appended but however during prediction it returns an empty list. That is very confusing.

Comment: Then `action` was neither 0 nor 1.

Comment: Obviously step would be called otherwise the custom environment would not at all work during prediction and training and would give me an error.

Comment: Yes, but there is another statement that says that if none of this occurs then jump onto the else statement which is a penalty of reward = -300000

Comment: yes but why the agent for each timestep is executing neither action 0 nor action 1.

Comment: I don't know. Where is the value of `action` determined and passed to `step`?

Comment: This is the value of action. self.action_space = Discrete(2) This is in the beginning of the class CostEnv. Also, during step function if you see the value of action is passed using if and else statement.

Comment: but my million dollar question is when I load my model again and use it to predict using another data-set of similar data-values and type. Why does it output me an empty list for self.grid_values and self.pv_values?

Comment: So if you add `print(action)` at the beginning of the `step` function, what is the output?

Comment: The value of action is (1,None).

Comment: Okay, that's the reason that the `else` part is entered and no values are appended to the lists. `(1, None)` is not equal to `0` and not equal to `1`. Can you please send me the million dollars ;)

Comment: Hahaha not yet. So how do I fix it?

Comment: Instead of comparing `action` to 0 or 1, maybe compare the first item in `action` to 0 or 1.

Comment: You mean instead having if action ==0 rather I should have if self.load[len(self.load)-self.episode_length] > self.line_max ==0: right? or can you type it as code if I am wrong?

Comment: I mean simply changing `action == 0` to `action[0] == 0` and `action == 1` to `action[0] == 1`.

Comment: and what about the None part. One thing that I did not understand was when I specified the action as discrete(2). This should be either 0 or 1. Why is it returning me a tuple of (1,None) as an output for the agent. Shouldn't it be a discrete set of actions that agent should take like 0 or 1?

Comment: I don't know that. You should read the documentation of the `Discrete` class or function (or its source code).

Comment: Hey @mkrieger1 I tried your suggestion but nothing changed? Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251977/discussion-between-sam-and-mkrieger1).